# Extracting dynamic <title> tags with PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm using the following (simplified) PHP script to extract a page's `<title>` tag:

```
function getTitle($Url){
    $contents = file_get_contents($Url);    
    $titlePattern = "/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/";    
       if (preg_match($titlePattern,$contents,$title) && strlen($title[1]) > 0){
            return $title[1];
    } else {
        return "No title found";
    }
}
```

Now this works for most websites, but I've run into some problems. For example, [this news article](http://readwrite.com/2014/11/05/android-lollipop-phones-tablets-when-will-they-update) has blank `<title>` tags when the script gets its contents.

Here's where it gets wierd: when the link is shared on Facebook, the article title comes up as *"Lollygagged: The Insufferable Wait For Android Updates - ReadWrite."* But if I print the `file_get_contents()`, that string is nowhere to be found.

1. Where is Facebook pulling the above title from?
2. Is there an alternate way for me to get the actual title? (without doing specific website-by-website scripts)

Thanks!

Comment: The title is prolly set with javascript/ajax. PHP can't execute this

Answer (score 0):

The link you have provided, there is no title in view source. It might be coming from javascript.
Check the source of your website. You will find `<title></title>`

Facebook is not getting it's actual title.